# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code is causing AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' and I do not how to fix it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import groupby


DATA = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]


def iter_something(rows):
    key_names = ['type', 'name', 'sub_name', 'pos', 's_type', 'x_type']
    chr_key_names = ['letter', 'no']
    for keys, group in groupby(rows, lambda row: row[:6]):
        result = dict(zip(key_names, keys))
        result['chr'] = [dict(zip(chr_key_names, row[6:])) for row in group]
        yield result


def convert(val):
    constructors = [int, str]
    for c in constructors:
        try:
            return c(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass


def main():
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
        parts = (line.split(',') for line in f)
        column = (part.strip() for part in parts)
        for object_ in iter_something(column):
            print(object_)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The error message is clear - `part` is a `list`, and therefore doesn't have a `strip` method.

Comment: `parts = (line.split(',') for line in f)`, `part` is a list, and it has no `strip` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have split your lines into columns:

```
parts = (line.split(',') for line in f)
```

then try to strip each list of columns:

```
column = (part.strip() for part in parts)
```

That won't work. Strip each column instead:

```
column = ([col.strip() for col in part] for part in parts)
```

You may want to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do the transformation from file to row-of-data instead however:

```
with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for object_ in iter_something(reader):
        print(object_)
```

The `skipinitialspace` option makes sure that a space directly following the delimiter is removed. A newline at the end of each line removed as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

`parts = (line.split(',') for line in f)` strip when you split as you are creating lists with split:

```
parts = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
```