# converting types of repeated list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists and I know each type of the elements `[Str, Str, Str, Int, Int, Int, Str, Int]`. I have a convert function which guesses the type:

```
def convert(val):
    constructors = [int, str]
    for c in constructors:
        try:
            return c(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

How is it possible to replace the convert function, because I know the type of each element (please see below the full code)?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import groupby


DATA = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]


def convert(val):
    constructors = [int, str]
    for c in constructors:
        try:
            return c(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass


def main():
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                data = [convert(part.strip()) for part in line.split(',')]
                print(data)
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you for all responses which have given me new ideas and therefore I also modified the code (*Method 1 - 4*), which is currently not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import groupby
import csv

parts = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'C', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    7, 'T', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
        ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]


def iter_something(rows):
    key_names = ['type', 'name', 'sub_name', 'pos', 's_type', 'x_type']
    chr_key_names = ['letter', 'no']
    for keys, group in groupby(rows, lambda row: row[:6]):
        result = dict(zip(key_names, keys))
        result['chr'] = [dict(zip(chr_key_names, row[6:])) for row in group]
        yield result


def main():
    #Method 1
    converters = [str, str, str, int, int, int, str, int]
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
        parts = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
        column = (con(part) for con, part in zip(converters, parts))
        for object_ in iter_something(column):
            print(object_)

    #Method 2
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
        parts = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
        parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[7] = int(parts[3]),\
                                                int(parts[4]),\
                                                int(parts[5]),\
                                                int(parts[7])
        column = (con(part) for con, part in zip(converters, parts))
        for object_ in iter_something(column):
            print(object_)

    #Method 3
    converters = [str, str, str, int, int, int, str, int]
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt", 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        for object_ in iter_something(reader):
            print(object_)

    #Method 4
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt", 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        reader[3], reader[4], reader[5], reader[7] = int(reader[3]),\
                                                    int(reader[4]),\
                                                    int(reader[5]),\
                                                    int(reader[7])

        for object_ in iter_something(reader):
            print(object_)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is the type of each element and what do you want the convert function to do?

Comment: converters = [str, str, str, int, int, int, str, int]

Comment: so you want to remove the try and cast because you know the structure will always be str, str, str, int, int, int, str, int?

Comment: correct, and I also updated my question above

Comment: it would be `for row in reader:row[0]...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip()` to pair up type with column:

```
converters = [str, str, str, int, int, int, str, int]

for line in f:
    data = [convert(part.strip()) 
            for convert, part in zip(converters, line.split(','))]
```

In your update you are again making the same mistake as you did in your other question; you are getting confused between rows and columns and are applying the technique to the rows:

```
parts = (line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
column = ([con(col) for con, col in zip(converters, row)] for row in parts)
```

Can I reiterate considering using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) once more, like I did for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571815/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-strip/26571839#26571839)? You are reinventing the CSV-parsing wheel a little here:

```
with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    converted = ([conv(col) for conv, col in zip(converters, row)] for row in reader)
```

Comment: yes, you can reiterate considering using the csv module. Is there any performance difference, between csv module and line.split(',')?

Comment: @user977828: The CSV module is coded in C and adds features such as correct handling of quoted columns (including using the delimiter and newlines in column values), etc. It'll be faster than using splitting and a list comprehension.

Comment: this like the other answer does not actually answer the question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes it does; the OP wants to know how to hardcode the type for each column when converting. Sure, some columns are already strings, but using `str()` on those is harmless, fast, and simplifies the code.

Comment: No, the OP has stated they already know the type ordering, as strings are already strings the OP only need cast to int. *How is it possible to replace the convert function, because I know the type of each element*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You interpreted the question the same way I did then. We just gave different approaches. You can disagree with that approach, but that doesn't I'm not answering the question asked.

Comment: Martijn Pieters and Padraic Cunningham both solution looking great. How would it be possible to apply both for CSV module?

Comment: @user977828: did you read my other answer carefully? You are making the same mistake again here; you are trying to convert each whole row now, not each column.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of `constructors` like you described at the start of your question, you could do this:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
data = [[con(val) for con, val in zip(constructors, line)] for line in reader]
```

That would give you a two-dimensional list; which is the structure that you wanted judging by the code that you provided.

---

**EDIT:** I modified the solution to work with the `csv` module, which you will need to import at the top. The above code would of course go within your `with` statement.

Comment: @user977828 I don't fully understand the update. What else does the solution need to do?

Comment: Your answer is actually working with `iter_something`, but I was carious how it would work with `csv` Module and also with @Padraic Cunningham solution.

Answer (score 1):

I will try actually answer your question you asked:

As the elements are already strings you just have to cast the ints:

```
data = ["Test", "A", "B01", "667214",  "1",   "14", 'G',"6"]

data[3], data[4], data[5], data[7],= int(data[3]),int(data[4]), int(data[5]), int(data[7])
```

So your main would look like:

```
def main():
    with open("/home/mic/tmp/test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                data = [part.strip() for part in line.split(',')]
                data[3], data[4], data[5], data[7],= int(data[3]),int(data[4]), int(data[5]), int(data[7])
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

But since you are already using a try, it would be better to add an exception for a ValueError

`except (IndexError,ValueError):`

You don't need a convert function, casting as ints in your main will suffice, no point casting strings that are already strings